# use JPA repository , jpql , native query query

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am new to springBoot i got confused when to use JPA repository, jpql, native query. what is difference between them while using it.

if i am  using the Jpa repository should i need to use. DAO class layer?

Answer (score 0):

JPA repository is used while using Spring-data framework.This framework automatically creates queries by looking at the method names defined in your reposiroty interface.

JPQL is used to write database independent queries. You can define these queries in the entity class. You will need to have a DAO class to execute JPQL queries.

If you want to write database specific queries, you can define native queries in the entiry. You will also need a DAO layer for executing these. However, native queries might or might not always be independent of the underlying database engine.

Comment: *You will also need a DAO layer for executing these*???  Spring Data JPA repos provide a straightforward means to execute both JPQL and native SQL queries via the `@Query(...)` annotation.

Comment: @AlanHay He has referred to JPA repository and JPQL as two separate things in the question. I believe he is referring to JPA's way of executing a JPQL query which involved calling createQuery(JPQL) method on entity-manager instance and this is supposed to be done in DAO layer. Same for Native query. Please let me know if I missed something.